# how to set default website in iis 7.5 when there are several websites in a site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a website that i put it in iis 7.5. for this purpose, I've create a new website (TestSite) in part of Sites in the my server at the iis, and i select ASP.NET v4.0 for application pool.  . then i right click on it and select add application... and i create an application that was my main website (TestMyWebSite). now, when i use http://myIP/TestMyWebSite/ ,at my browser, i see my website and no problem. but i want use http://myIP/ for showing my website. please help me

Answer (score 12):

Select the site in IIS, open Binding, give IP and port number 80 and Save.

Port number 80 is default port for your IP address , thus binding site to port number 80 makes it default site for IP.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i set my ip in Binding. but when i insert my ip in browser, i received this error : HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: i have a site in iis and several website and wcf service in my site. and i want one of the this websites be the main website that run with my ip, while the now my main website run this way: myIP/myMainwesite

Comment: I have set up http://52.253.89.211/ so the site works but https://52.253.89.211/ gives the same error